# How do I make the plot generated marker more noticeable?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, plot

I have the coordinate indicating the start of each letter within a word. I have set the plot function to make a red circle at that coordinate like so:

[image]

The problem is that the paper I am adding this image to has a structure of 2 columns per page. And when I add 2 of the above image to the same column, the circles become very small and difficult to notice.

I tried instead of circles to make triangles or pentagrams. I get the same result, they become too small to distinguish.

How can I make this more distinguishable? Especially when its printed in black and white.

Comment: change the marker size? `plot(...'MarkerSize',30)`?

Comment: That is great. Thank you. That will work. Can you please add this as an answer so that I can accept it. Also do you know what the default marker size is?

Comment: Also increase line width: `plot(...,'markersize',30,'linewidth',8)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the marker size of the markers, and\or overlay two different markers one of the other. For example:

```
x=1:100;
y=rand(1,100);
plot(x,y); hold on
n=20:20:60;
plot(x(n),y(n),'r+','MarkerSize',30,'LineWidth',2);
plot(x(n),y(n),'ro','MarkerSize',15,'LineWidth',2);
```

[image]

There are many other degrees of freedom you can use to add \ change to this. It is a very basic question that you could have answered yourself if you [read the documentation of plot in TMW website](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html).